# jQuery Validation show error message for only one specific select field (bootstrap-select)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using bootstrap-select plugin along with jQuery Validation plug in and am adding some custom error states to the select dropdowns (red border). I almost have everything working as I would like. The one issue I cannot seem to figure out is how to display error text along with the custom error border I created on ONE of the input fields. I added an addMethod to the form validation which is checking for a min age of 18 which is working but the Error message needs to show along with the custom red border I have created when they select an age that does not meet the requirements of the addMethod (must be 18)

https://codepen.io/mDDDD/pen/qBZWpbj

html:

```
  <div class="custom-select-box">
                          <select class="selectpicker select-input multiple select-month" name="dobMonth"
                            id="selectMonth">
                            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Month</option>
                            <option value="January">January</option>
                            <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
                            <option value="March">March</option>
                            <option value="April">April</option>
                            <option value="May">May</option>
                            <option value="June">June</option>
                            <option value="July">July</option>
                            <option value="August">August</option>
                            <option value="September">September</option>
                            <option value="October">October</option>
                            <option value="November">November</option>
                            <option value="December">December</option>
                          </select>

                          <div class="dropdown-caret-div">
                            <i class="fal fa-angle-up"></i>
                            <i class="fal fa-angle-down"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="custom-select-box">
                          <select class="selectpicker select-input  multiple select-day" name="dobDay" id="selectDay">
                            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Day</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="12">12</option>
                            <option value="13">13</option>
                            <option value="14">14</option>
                            <option value="15">15</option>
                            <option value="16">16</option>
                            <option value="17">17</option>
                            <option value="18">18</option>
                            <option value="19">19</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="21">21</option>
                            <option value="22">22</option>
                            <option value="23">23</option>
                            <option value="24">24</option>
                            <option value="25">25</option>
                            <option value="26">26</option>
                            <option value="27">27</option>
                            <option value="28">28</option>
                            <option value="29">29</option>
                            <option value="30">30</option>
                            <option value="31">31</option>
                          </select>
                          <div class="dropdown-caret-div">
                            <i class="fal fa-angle-up"></i>
                            <i class="fal fa-angle-down"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="custom-select-box">
                          <select class="selectpicker select-input multiple select-year" name="dobYear" id="selectYear">
                            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Year</option>
                            <option value="2020">2020</option>
                            <option value="2019">2019</option>
                            <option value="2018">2018</option>
                            <option value="2017">2017</option>
                            <option value="2016">2016</option>
                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                            <option value="2014">2014</option>
                            <option value="2013">2013</option>
                            <option value="2012">2012</option>
                            <option value="2011">2011</option>
                            <option value="2010">2010</option>
                            <option value="2009">2009</option>
                            <option value="2008">2008</option>
                            <option value="2007">2007</option>
                            <option value="2006">2006</option>
                            <option value="2005">2005</option>
                            <option value="2004">2004</option>
                            <option value="2003">2003</option>
                            <option value="2002">2002</option>
                            <option value="2001">2001</option>
                            <option value="2000">2000</option>
                            <option value="1999">1999</option>
                            <option value="1998">1998</option>
                            <option value="1997">1997</option>
                            <option value="1996">1996</option>
                            <option value="1995">1995</option>
                            <option value="1994">1994</option>
                            <option value="1993">1993</option>
                            <option value="1992">1992</option>
                            <option value="1991">1991</option>
                            <option value="1990">1990</option>
                            <option value="1989">1989</option>
                            <option value="1988">1988</option>
                            <option value="1987">1987</option>
                            <option value="1986">1986</option>
                            <option value="1985">1985</option>
                            <option value="1984">1984</option>
                            <option value="1983">1983</option>
                            <option value="1982">1982</option>
                            <option value="1981">1981</option>
                            <option value="1980">1980</option>
                            <option value="1979">1979</option>
                            <option value="1978">1978</option>
                            <option value="1977">1977</option>
                            <option value="1976">1976</option>
                            <option value="1975">1975</option>
                            <option value="1974">1974</option>
                            <option value="1973">1973</option>
                            <option value="1972">1972</option>
                            <option value="1971">1971</option>
                            <option value="1970">1970</option>
                            <option value="1969">1969</option>
                            <option value="1968">1968</option>
                            <option value="1967">1967</option>
                            <option value="1966">1966</option>
                            <option value="1965">1965</option>
                            <option value="1964">1964</option>
                            <option value="1963">1963</option>
                            <option value="1962">1962</option>
                            <option value="1961">1961</option>
                            <option value="1960">1960</option>
                            <option value="1959">1959</option>
                            <option value="1958">1958</option>
                            <option value="1957">1957</option>
                            <option value="1956">1956</option>
                            <option value="1955">1955</option>
                            <option value="1954">1954</option>
                            <option value="1953">1953</option>
                            <option value="1952">1952</option>
                            <option value="1951">1951</option>
                            <option value="1950">1950</option>
                            <option value="1949">1949</option>
                            <option value="1948">1948</option>
                            <option value="1947">1947</option>
                            <option value="1946">1946</option>
                            <option value="1945">1945</option>
                            <option value="1944">1944</option>
                            <option value="1943">1943</option>
                            <option value="1942">1942</option>
                            <option value="1941">1941</option>
                            <option value="1940">1940</option>
                            <option value="1939">1939</option>
                            <option value="1938">1938</option>
                            <option value="1937">1937</option>
                            <option value="1936">1936</option>
                            <option value="1935">1935</option>
                            <option value="1934">1934</option>
                            <option value="1933">1933</option>
                            <option value="1932">1932</option>
                            <option value="1931">1931</option>
                            <option value="1930">1930</option>
                          </select>
                          <div class="dropdown-caret-div">
                            <i class="fal fa-angle-up"></i>
                            <i class="fal fa-angle-down"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- select box row-->
```

jQuery:

```
 $userInfoForm.validate({
      debug: true,
      ignore: [],
      rules: {

        userIs: {
          required: true,
        },
        dobMonth: {
          required: true,
        },
        dobDay: {
          required: true,
        },
        dobYear: {
          minAge18: true,
          minAge10: false,
          required: true,
        },
       
      },
      messages: {
        userIs: 'This field is required.',
        dobMonth: 'Date of birth is required.',
        dobDay: 'Month is required.',
        dobYear: {
          minAge18:
            'We&#39;re sorry but you need to be at least 18 years old to register.',
          required: 'Year is required.',
        },
                 },
      errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if ($(element).is('select')) {
          $(element).parent('div').addClass('dropdown-has-error');
        } else if ($(element).attr('name') === 'userIs') {
          $(element).siblings('label.select-role').addClass('radio-has-error');
        } else {
          element.attr('placeholder', error.text());
        }
      },
      success: function (label, element) {
        $(element).parent('div').removeClass('dropdown-has-error');
        $(element).siblings('label.select-role').removeClass('radio-has-error');
      }



$('.selectpicker').on('change', function () {
    $(this).valid();

    if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {
      $(this).parent('div').addClass('dropdown-has-error');
    } else {
      $(this).parent('div').removeClass('dropdown-has-error');
    }
  });



 //add validator method - user must be at least 18 years of age
  $.validator.addMethod(
    'minAge18',
    function (value, element) {
      var yearToday = new Date().getFullYear();
      value = parseInt(value, 10);

      return yearToday - value >= 18;
    },
    'Update minAge18 error message in validator'
  );
```

css:

```
.error {
  color: red;
}

.radio-has-error::before {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.dropdown-has-error {
  border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

Comment: You think it might be important to show us the HTML and CSS for this considering that's the part where things show up?

Comment: @Sparky, you are right, sorry about that :)

Comment: You keep asking questions about jQuery Validate and I keep posting answers, and yet you've given no feedback whatsoever about why the answer is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have error messages because you've eliminated them from the `errorPlacement` function.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if ($(element).is('select')) {
      $(element).parent('div').addClass('dropdown-has-error');
    } else if ($(element).attr('name') === 'userIs') {
      $(element).siblings('label.select-role').addClass('radio-has-error');
    } else {
      element.attr('placeholder', error.text());
    }
  },
```

Any `select` is going to hit the first conditional, which only adds a class.

```
if ($(element).is('select')) {
    $(element).parent('div').addClass('dropdown-has-error');
```

The default `errorPlacement` function contains something like the following, which you've neglected to include anywhere...

```
error.insertAfter(element);
```

You have a `element.attr('placeholder', error.text())`, which will simply change the `placeholder` attribute into the error message, but only when the other conditionals fail.  I don't think using the `placeholder` for error messages is proper GUI since that's not what a `placeholder` is supposed to be... and AFAIK, there is no `placeholder` on `select` elements.

So if you're missing messages, it's because you've overwritten the default `errorPlacement` without inserting the `error` object anywhere into your DOM.

That being said, you should not be using `errorPlacement` for adding classes.  You should only use it for placing the message into your layout.  Once placed, the plugin toggles the message.  If you add classes here, then you would need to remove them somehow, which is what you're doing with the `success` callback. However, this all just isn't quite right.

- [`errorPlacement`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) is for placing the message into the layout.
- [`success`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success) is for leveraging the message itself when the element is valid, such as placing a green checkmark.

If you want to add and remove classes, then use the [`highlight`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight) and [`unhighlight`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#unhighlight) callback functions as that's exactly what these are here to do.