# jQuery Validation validating element even though set to "required: false"

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have one checkbox on my form that is not required, I have it set to required "false" in my rules but it is still validating and adding a class of "error-state" to the parent. Not sure if there is a way to just force validation on this single element?

HTML:

```
 <div class="form__input-row row--flex">
          <div class="form-field row--flex">          
            <input id="copay-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_eligible" class="form-input--checkbox">
            <label class="form-label--opt-in row--flex align--flex-start">
              <div class="opt-in__pseudo-input"></div>
              <span class="form-label--opt-in__text">
                I would like to receive a Card.               
              </span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#cardForm").validate({
    rules :{
     checkbox_eligible: {
      required: false,
    },
  },
errorPlacement: function (error, $element) {
    var inputType = $element.attr('type'),
      $parentField = $element.closest('.form-field');

    if (inputType === 'checkbox') {
      $parentField.addClass('error-state');
      $parentField.append(error);
    } else if (inputType === 'radio') {
      error.insertAfter($parentField);
    } else {
        $parentField.append(error);
      }
    } else {
      error.insertAfter($element);
    }
  },
```

Comment: `$parentField.addClass('error-state')` - Please carefully review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63238085/594235) on your previous question where I pointed out the same mistake several months ago.

Comment: In other words, your custom `errorPlacement` function adds a class that nothing else will remove automatically.  You've effectively bypassed the normal validation flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it is still validating and adding a class of "error-state" to the parent.

It's "validating" because you have a field with a rule that needs to be evaluated every time it's triggered.   However, it is not "failing" validation.

In this case, it's your own `errorPlacement` function that is adding the `error-state` class...

```
errorPlacement: function (error, $element) {
    ....

    if (inputType === 'checkbox') {
      $parentField.addClass('error-state');
      .....
    }
},
```

This is not what you're supposed to do with `errorPlacement`.  It's only purpose is for *placing* the error message within your layout.  It is not supposed to be used to add/remove any validation classes.

And since you have no code in place to remove this class, it's going to stay there.  Meanwhile, the validation plugin considers this field as "valid" despite the insertion of your custom class.

If you want to add/remove classes or do other things upon invalid/valid validation, you would use the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions.

---

**Quoting myself from [an answer on one of your other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63238085/594235):**

> *"... you **should not be using `errorPlacement` for adding
> classes**. You should only use it for placing the message into your
> layout. ..."*

---

There is also no need to ever use `required: false` as that is the default.  If you find yourself setting `required` to `false`, it means something else is wrong with your approach.

> Not sure if there is a way to just force validation on this single element?

No idea what you're really trying to achieve, but you can programmatically trigger validation on a field with the `.valid()` method.

```
$('#my_field').valid();
```

However, this only forces the plugin to evaluate the field, which will not fix your issue, because your custom `errorPlacement` function adds a validation class that the plugin is unable to remove.